# Loading properties of Property file JBOSS-7

Tags: jboss7.x

I have done my configuration as per https://community.jboss.org/message/750465
I need to load a key from properties-service.xml which has below attributes.

```
<attribute name="Properties">
project.userName=xxxxx          
project.userType=xxxxx
project.userToken=xxxx
```

My code access these properties as below
    Properties globalSystemProperties = System.getProperties();
    Enumeration keys = (Enumeration) globalSystemProperties.propertyNames();

I am not seeing my key list when iterate , What Could be the reason?

Comment: Linked thread clearly says properties-service.xml is not supported in JBoss 7, so how exactly have you done your configuration and how you expect it to work?

Comment: yes it is clear. I moved the properties to property file under module. But Still I m not getting the expected keys with System.getProperties(). How to load my properties as System properties () as I donot like to change my code with JBOSS4 to JBOSS7 migration.

Comment: I did not copy my property file to WEB_INF but i like to keep it inside the JBOSS7 external to my jars , wars is this possible ?

Comment: With -P switch I managed to load my properties. But it did not load w adding the property files to jar file may be my jar is loading later.

Comment: why would that be expected? I don't see anywhere in the thread saying that module properties should be usable with `System.getProperties()`. The instructions at [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath) explicitly mention using getResourceAsStream(), not System.getProperties().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that it isn't supported anymore, like the [thread you linked says](https://community.jboss.org/message/750465):

> jaikiran pai Dec 19, 2011 10:53 PM (in response to David Robison)
>
> It doesn't exist in AS7.

[This page](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath) tells a way of doing it with modules, but that will not work using `System.getProperties()`, it will only place them on classpath.

If you want your properties in the System.getProperties() code, I only can think of these options:

1. use --property or -P startup parameter pointing to your file, like explained [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Command+line+parameters)
2. populate them as `<system-property/>` in the configuration file
3. set them to actual system properties on startup or in code
4. use Spring or similar to add them as system properties

The first option is I guess the closest you can have.